# Hard drive backup issue in Mavericks

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup

My hard drive had some bad sectors recently, so I backed up, re-formatted, and clean installed Mavericks.

Everything seemed to work fine until couple days ago when I tried to look at some photos I recently imported to iPhoto, things got stuck and sometimes wouldn't move at all for up to 40 seconds, I knew it was a hard drive issue.

I tried to use the os x disk util to verify and repair disk but it all came up green.

when I try to run time machine it transfers REALLY REALLY SLOW and than gets stuck and says backup failed.

what should I do?

Comment: I bet on "Disk I/O errors" in Console.app

Comment: yeah i do see a lot of disk i/o errors. problem is how do i recover my data? i can still boot and use it but i wan to keep all my files. is there any programs like spinrite for mac that keeps reading till it finds something so i can recover and replace drive?

Comment: You won't be able to backup all your files. You can't retrieve the data stored on the dead sectors.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you few years ago.

You definitely have the sympthoms of bad sectors. If you can't backup with Time Machine I advise you to back your data from the finder by yourself and skipping the files that can't be read.

---

Edit : You won't be able to backup all your files. You can't retrieve the data stored on the dead sectors.

Answer (score 1):

Open Console in your Utility folder.

Type "disk" in the search (Filter) window

Look if you have disk I/O errors.

If you do see them (like a lots of them), your disk is bad, so back up, and get new disk.